# Named boxes with links compatibility

Tags: hyperref, navigation, xsavebox

I'm using xsavebox package for saving and using named boxes (I want the boxes to have names like X.1.3) and I want to make links to these boxes but they are not compatible with any kind of referencing. Any ideas?

```
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{navigator}

\anchor{K.1.1}
\begin{xlrbox}{X.1.3}
    \anchor{X.1.3}
    \jumplink{K.1.1}{K.1.1}
\end{xlrbox}
...
\xusebox{X.1.3}
```

Using it gives an error:

```
pdfTeX error (ext4): link annotations cannot be inside an XForm.
```

Comment: as the error says: links can't be inside an xform. So no it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this answer from Alexander Grahn, so I'm sharing it here.  [Alexander's Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/agrahn)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\namedsbox[2]{%
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname\else%
    \expandafter\newsavebox\csname#1\endcsname%
  \fi%
  \expandafter\sbox\csname#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand\usenamedbox[1]{\expandafter\usebox\csname#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
  \namedsbox{my named box}{\hyperlink{target}{Click!}}%
  \hypertarget{target}{Target.}
  \usenamedbox{my named box}
\end{document}
```